# $_POST/$_REQUEST is empty on web service when request is made from postman chrome app or from mobile

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, post

`$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` are empty in the web service when a request is made from the postman chrome app, using curl or from mobile.

The serialized post is not blank. It has the input parameter `name`, but no value.
`var_dump` is also showing blank array.

I am getting parameters with a `GET` request and when the request is made through a webpage html form.

I am using codeigniter.

Comment: How can we produce that problem?

Comment: I am not authorized to disclose the web service link, i am pretty sure its not the code error its seems to be something related to configuration.

Comment: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: REQUEST');       also included these headers .